# Confirmation on boolean expression simplifications

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logic, solution-verification, boolean-algebra

This is expression no.1: $(A+B’)\cdot C + A \cdot C $.

So i think these are the simplification steps: $$(A+B’)\cdot C + A \cdot C = A\cdot C + B' \cdot C + A \cdot C = B' \cdot C + A \cdot C => C \cdot(A + B')$$

And this is expression no.2: $(A + B’ + C’)\cdot(A’ + B’ + C’)\cdot(A’ + B’ + C’)$.

So i think these are the simplification steps: $$(A + B’ + C’)\cdot(A’ + B’ + C’)\cdot(A’ + B’ + C’) = (A + B’ + C’)\cdot(A’ + B’ + C’) = (B' + C')\cdot (B' + C') => (B' + C') $$

Are these simplifications correct?

Comment: Looks correct to me

Comment: It looks correct to me to and presumably at least 2 other people. A self answer would be appropriate here, if you felt inclined.